# Standalone Flash application + Facebook

Tags: facebook, actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

So here is the thing...
I need a standalone flash application that receives by socket an image and then publishes it on facebook.
The few methods i've seen use php but in this case i really would like to use only the standalone.

Ideas on how to accomplish this? Is it possible?

Comment: as I know there is no native Flacebook api for flash, so you will still have to deal with JS. Also I am not sure that what you want is a flash application. This will run on the client....

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do can be accomplished from the client without server scripting as well.

Have a look on these links

http://code.google.com/p/facebook-actionscript-api/

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/facebook.html

It's an AS facebook api and the Adobe site has some very useful examples on how to set this up.

After you achieve a login and you have a working connection to the Fb api then you can upload your picture to the user's albums using the api from within AS.